# Javafx: Multi Threading a reminder notification

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am creating a system that notify user of appointment time. My Question: **Is it good to create a Thread when ever the user add a new appointment that is going to be listening to when ever the appointment date is and display a notification by the right bottom corner**

My Code

```
DateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
Timer timer = new Timer();

private void appointmentNotification() throws ParseException {
    //Convert 12hour time to 24hour
    String dateValues = date + " " + time;
    Date dateParse = inFormat.parse(dateValues);

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Notifications noti = Notifications.create();
            noti.text("Doctor "+doc+" has an Appointment with Patient "+patient);
            noti.title("Appointment");
            noti.hideAfter(Duration.seconds(10));
            noti.position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    noti.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }, outFormat.parse(outFormat.format(dateParse)));
}
```

I imagine if the user added 50 appointments, There will be 50 Thread running

Comment: I assume the appointments are added to a database at some point? If so, just create a single background thread to poll the database at regular intervals. When an appointment approaches, show the reminder.

Comment: Note that a `java.util.Timer` only uses a single background thread.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have one thread checking all relevant  appointments ?

Comment: @c0der thats way am trying to implement but i can't figure it out

Comment: @Slaw yes i know. But how to use that single Thread to handle multiple Reminder Notifications

Comment: So the question boils down to how do I iterate over all appointments, doesn't it ?

Comment: @c0der Yes it does

Comment: So change the question and post [mcve] demonstrating the issue. The posted code does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i followed the logic Zephyr gave in the comment and it worked for me.

**I assume the appointments are added to a database at some point? If so, just create a single background thread to poll the database at regular intervals. When an appointment approaches, show the reminder.**

Code:

```
private void displayAppointmentNotification() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ps = HospitalDB.getCon().prepareStatement("Select * From Notification");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {

                    if (rs.getString("Reminder").contentEquals(dateFormat.format(new Date()))) {
                        Notifications noti = Notifications.create();
                        noti.text("Doctor " + rs.getString("Doctor") + " has an Appointment with Patient " + rs.getString("Patient"));
                        noti.title("Appointment");
                        noti.hideAfter(Duration.seconds(30));
                        noti.position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            noti.show();
                        });

                        //Change The Appointment Status to Done
                        ps = HospitalDB.getCon().prepareStatement("Update Appointment Set Status=? Where Patient=? and Doctor=?");
                        ps.setString(1, "Done");
                        ps.setString(2, rs.getString("Patient"));
                        ps.setString(3, rs.getString("Doctor"));
                        ps.executeUpdate();

                        populateTable();
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1 * 1000);
}
```

The background Thread will always look at the Dates in database and if its the same with the system Date it displays Notification